# PHP MySQL is not getting anything from the database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Trying to get all the users from my database, yet when I do so, the query fails.

Attempting to do so with

```
 $userNames = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Login");
```

Where in PHPMyAdmin the database has a few records in the table login.
I checked if the connection is connected, its connected.

Is there any reason this wouldn't work?

Here is a [examplepage](http://tst.burngames.net/Burn%20Games/login/), you can try logging in with Username and Password.

EDIT: From the example page, here is the code used to test:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "<br />";
} else {
    echo "Connected to MySQL!<br />";
}
if(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Login")){
    echo "Query good!<br />";
} else {
    echo "Query bad!<br />";
}
```

EDIT 2: Here is a screenshot of the table existing, and the data existing:
[image: Something]

Comment: And `$conn` is a valid resource?

Comment: What does `mysqli_error()` return when it fails?

Comment: Added example code, (and its $con). If you go to the demo page and try it, it will say that it could connect to $con.

Comment: Barmar, it returns nothing.

Comment: Dave, it is a table. I suppose I could send you a censored screenshot..

Comment: Edited in to the original question.

Comment: What is the returned value of mysqli_num_rows?

Comment: If `mysqli_query()` returns `false`, `mysqli_error()` should always return an error message.

Comment: `mysqli_connect_errno()` doesn't take an argument -- when the connection fails, `$con` is `false`. You should be getting an error on that line because you're passing the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting enabled, so you'll see errors like that.

Comment: It might be that the user you are logging into the database does not have select access on the Login table.

Comment: Barmer.. mysqli_query() return false with no error. Also, mysqli_connect_ernno() does take a argument. And Error Reporting for what? You need to specify.

Pieter, it returns nothing. In the example page, I added a rows for when it processes.

Comment: Orangepill, I just checked. It does.

Comment: did you pass a db name as the fourth parameter to mysqli_connect or did you call mysqli_select_db

Comment: I used a database name..

Comment: just to try to isolate the problem try changing your query to `SELECT 1`;

Comment: Nothing. It just doesn't get anything..

I tried making a second database, it still wouldn't work..

If this can't be answered I'll just figure something else out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this

```
$con = StartDatabase("localhost", "username", "password", "mydatabase");

function StartDatabase($dblocation, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $dbname){
 $link = mysqli_connect($dblocation, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $dbname);
  if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
 return $link;
}

if(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Login")){
    echo "Query good!<br />";
} else {
    echo "Query bad!<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the else of the query to get an error output:

```
echo "Error code ({$con->errno}): {$con->error}";
```

Comment: Can you post your $con string. Just edit out the info you don't want shown.

Comment: $con = mysqli_connect("pdb1.awardspace.com", "**********", "*******", "*******");

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$con = new mysqli("pdb1.awardspace.com", "*******", "****", "*******");

$query = "SELECT * FROM Login";

if ( !$con->query($query) ) {
    echo "Query bad!<br />";
    echo mysqli_connect_error() . "<br />";
    echo "Error code ({$sql->errno}): {$sql->error}";
} else {
    echo "Query good!<br />";
}
$con->close();
```

Comment: there was an extra backtick(`) in there after login. I have removed it so have an eye for that.

Comment: What?
I also tried this, and I get a 500 from
`if (!$con -> query($query))`

Comment: What do you mean a 500?

Comment: Ah never mind. I just decided to switch to something else..
And by 500 I mean PHP server error.

Comment: Did you edit the $con string, it is different than your orig.